# Get google plus user friends

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, google-plus, google-contacts-api

In the [Google+ API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/search) there is a method to search for public friends.

However, I do not see a way to get user friends. Is there any way to get the Google+ user's friends?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There currently is no API access to circles and friends in Googel+. There is an [open feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=9) you can star to get notified if an API method is added.

Alternatively you can use the [Google Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/). This has the downside of being a scarier permission dialog because there is not a read only permission.

Comment: Just wanted to add a note here, you can list people a user has made visible to your app using this api call: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.people.list