# Google+ iOS SDK get friends list?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus

Is it possible to get contacts list with Google+ iOS SDK ? Or is this possible using Google+ REST API ?

Comment: There is another solution, using Contacts API, check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820536/get-google-user-friends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not **currently** possible. The SDKs provide wrappers around the REST API and the REST API does not currently offer this ability.

The comment by Almas about using the Contact API is a good suggestion, but the list of circled people and the list of people in the Contacts are likely quite different for most people.