# How to Fetch Google Plus circles in IOS Sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, google-plus

I am using Google Plus integration where I have to fetch circles of user.

I am passing the Url:https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/Your_User_Id/people/visible?key=APP_Key.

I am getting the response as:

```
{ error = { code = 403; errors = ( { domain = global; message = Forbidden; reason = forbidden; } ); message = Forbidden; }; }
```

What kind of permission do I need for This request?

Comment: i think you must see this link for your question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820536/get-google-user-friends

Comment: Thanks for the response.It is one year old post.May be they have allowed now since it is written in docs that they allow fetching circles using the url I used above but getting forbidden response like above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only do this for the signed in user - so the "Your_User_Id" should always be "me". It's fine to pass the app key as well, but you must be making the call with an oAuth 2.0 token  from a user who has signed in to your app. You can see all the details here: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/people#retrieve_a_collection_of_people

Basically you'd need to implement sign-in, if you haven't already, then you can use the plusService in the GPPSignIn sharedInstance:

```
GTLQueryPlus *query =
    [GTLQueryPlus queryForPeopleListWithUserId:@"me"
                                    collection:kGTLPlusCollectionVisible];
[[[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] plusService] executeQuery:query
        completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                            GTLPlusPeopleFeed *peopleFeed,
                            NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
              GTMLoggerError(@"Error: %@", error);
            } else {
              // Get an array of people from GTLPlusPeopleFeed
              NSArray* peopleList = [peopleFeed.items retain];
            }
        }];
```

That is calling the URL that you're giving there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.This is the exact answer along with what I was missing is the scopes permission.[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
           @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.moments.write",
           @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me",@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login",@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me",@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
           nil] :...This solved my problem.

Comment: One more thing Ian,Does google+ API allow to send messages to friends in circle or some kind of invitation to friends or any means of communication in the circle.I read the API but do not get any clue regarding this.

Comment: You can't send one automatically (e.g. via an API call), but you can use the share functionality, and pre-fill some text for the user: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share

Comment: But that one is being shared in the circle itself.Not as a private message to a friend.Am I right?

Comment: You can share to a singe person, which is the closest equivalent to a private message.

Comment: Exact solution. But unable to get Email Ids of the people. Please can you explain how can we get email of the people.  Thanks in advance.